# How do I define these terms in my function

Tags: r

I am trying to create a function GP(x)=N*(FMR/(ED*AE)) where x represents the days of the year (from 1 to 365).

My problem is that I want N and FMR to equal a certain number when x< and > a certain day of the year and I have no idea how to code this in a normal function code. i.e. GP<-function(...)

Comment: Can you include in the question how you would normally code the function?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an `if`/`else` clause or you can use `ifelse()` to make the value of FMR and N conditional on x

```
GP <- function (x,ED,AE){
    # option 1, use an if/else clause
    if(x < 100)
        FMR = 10
    else 
        FMR = 20
    # option 2: use ifelse()
    N = ifelse(x < 100,10,20)

    return(  N*(FMR/(ED*AE)) ) 
}
```